# Stop View flexing react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How do I make the View not flex and take size of the content Inside in react native.

[image: React Native]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `alignSelf` style property to `flex-start`. for example:

```
<View style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>...</View>
```

> `alignSelf` controls how a child aligns in the cross direction, overriding the `alignItems` of the parent. It works like `align-self` in CSS (default: auto). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self for more details.